# Try catch with async / await in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using VueJS/Nuxt and Vuex store, and I have the following method defined:

```
async UpdateData () {
  try {
    await this.$store.dispatch('updateMyData', this.data)
    successMsg({ message: 'Data updated successfully' })
  } catch (e) {
    errorMsg({ message: 'Some error' })
  }
}
```

The problem is that I have not yet created the action 'updateMyData', so in my console I see the error `'[vuex] unknown action type: updateMyData'`

However, still the `successMsg()` is executed and I get the message 'Data updated successfully'.

My assumption was that if await... fails, it will go to the catch block.

Can you please help with what is wrong with my code and how I can correct it.

Comment: Are you familiar with promises? `await` / `async` are basically a new syntax for using promises. If the promise version of this code doesn't fail, the `await` version will not either.

Comment: I have not used promises much. But looking at the above could why do you think it's not catching the error?

Comment: @acdcjunior - did you read the question? namely, the statement directly under the code block.

Comment: No harm. All just trying help. So upvote my answer - because it is the best answer after all :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is not an actual promise error, it's a warning from Vuex, saying that the `'updateMyData'` action hasn't been registered anywhere in your Vuex store. The message comes from a simple console.log(/error/warn) instead of a `throw` or `reject()`, which is why it doesn't fail in your function here.

Comment: So, this means that if I create the action and if that action returns an error for some reason, then the error will be caught?

Comment: I believe so, since the $dispatch() function is returning the promise that the action returns

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an await expression not returning a Promise object, it turns what is passed in into a "resolved promise". This simply means your undefined function is returned immediately as if it Resolved. Hence, it doesn't reject and the `await` doesn't throw.

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

This comes from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description

Comment: Right -the reason for the question mark. kingdaro's code is likely correct. I deleted since it wasn't directly related to the question.

Comment: Although `dispatch` tipically returns a `Promise`, when the action doesn't exist, which is the case, it return `undefined` (just tested it). You hit the nail in the head, +1!